# Rendered result in eevee is blurry/pixelated

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm very new to Blender and have just made my first character and now trying to render an image It looks fine in the viewport but the rendered image becomes pixelated when zooming in and is not as sharp as you see below:
[image]

I have tested various outputs using different combinations of the below tweaks (mostly changes to render properties) over the past few hours but nothing seems to work:

1. Increasing the render sample and viewport sample count to 1000
2. Removing DOF by setting max size to 0px
3. Setting Film > Filter Size to 0px
4. Increasing/decreasing scene resolution
5. Increasing/decreasing camera focal length

Please help! Appreciate any advice at all on what I'm doing wrong please, I might have missed something or made some rookie mistakes as its my first time, the .blend file is also attached here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19NZLUMHT1dSKcCv95hjF3BS1wPjKSOum/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello could you please pack the images before sharing? (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that will make an image less pixelated is more pixels. But no matter how big is the resolution, you will always end up seeing the pixels if you zoom enough on the image.

[image]

The reason why it's not like in the viewport is simply because the viewport literally is constantly recalculating what it sees at its native resolution. When you zoom in, you only change what the viewport display, you don't change the viewport display.

Eevee's sampling will just change the rendering quality, not the resolution.
DOF max size only affects the DOF rendering, which you are not even using in your scene.
The filter size is basically kind of like an antialiasing / blur.
Focal length is basically your camera's FOV.

Your current resolution is 4K UHD, that's bigger than what most people's FHD monitors can display.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense! I understand better how the viewport resolution works now, thanks very much for your answer and explanation.